# How can I enable memory and objects profiling in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, profiling

I ran rake test:profile and got a report of:

```
    process_time: 62 ms
          memory: unsupported
         objects: unsupported
```

How can I enable the memory and objects component?

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and I have ruby-prof listed in my Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this patched version of 1.92

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --patch gcdata --name gcdata
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, so you may no longer need an answer, but I'll add something here for anyone else that may run into it searching for 'memory: unsupported'.

Getting the memory allocated and objects allocated information requires running a patched version of ruby. For anyone that may still be using 1.8.7, this post describes patching ruby 1.8.7:
http://patshaughnessy.net/2010/9/28/ruby187gc-patch

I haven't found a patched version of 1.9.2, but this other stackoverflow answer seems to imply 1.9.2 has the GC profiling built-in:
[Is there a way to profile ruby 1.9.2 scripts with memory allocation reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156907/is-there-a-way-to-profile-ruby-1-9-2-scripts-with-memory-allocation-reports)

I happen to be looking at an old app still running 1.8.7 right now, so I haven't looked further at 1.9.2