# What profilers are available for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, profiling

I found this SO question that mentions the GC profiler: [Is there a way to profile ruby 1.9.2 scripts with memory allocation reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156907/is-there-a-way-to-profile-ruby-1-9-2-scripts-with-memory-allocation-reports)

Are there any other profilers? Preferably free, easy to use, and work with Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [built-in profiler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ruby2/section3.html) available with "-r profile", which I've used happily.
There's also a gem called [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/).